# Add all the repos from a user using git in python

Tags: python, git, github, github-api

I have a function: `def get_repos(user)`. What I want is to add that user's public repo names from Github to a `set()` in Python. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There's no way for you to list all of my repositories. They're on my machine (not on Bitbucket or GitLab).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was referring to the public repos that are on Github.

Comment: In that case, you need to refine your question (which was kind of the point of the original comment). Note that there's no *Git* way to do this: you must use the GItHub API. Even then you may not be able to see someone's repositories.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-a-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as illustrated by "[Build a Dynamic Portfolio With the Github API](https://medium.com/swlh/build-a-dynamic-portfolio-with-the-github-api-6d74081e5164)"  from **[Ramki Pitchala](https://github.com/Ramko9999)**, using, as commented, the [Users REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-a-user=):

```py
def getRepos():
    try:
        url = "https://api.github.com/users/Ramko9999/repos"
        headers = {"Accept":"application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json"}
        repos = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=(USERNAME,TOKEN)).json()
        projects = []
        for repo in repos:
            if repo["homepage"]:
                project = {
                    "id": repo["id"],
                    "name": repo["name"],
                    "url": repo["html_url"],
                    "description": repo["description"],
                    "topics":repo["topics"],
                    "images": repo["homepage"].split(";")
                }
                projects.append(project)
        return {"projects": projects, "error": False}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": True, "message": str(e)}
```

(Replace `Ramko9999` by the actual username you need)